# the number of ways a planar graph can be partitioned

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory, set-partition, graph-laplacian

i have a connected planar graph to cut into k parts and want to know how many possible solutions there are. it clearly depends on the shape of the graph since nodes all in a row cannot be partitioned as many ways as the same number of nodes in a bunch.

the stirling number of the second kind gives the number of ways a set can be k-way partitioned, but in this problem the k planar subgraphs have to stay connected, so there are fewer possibilities.

can the question be approached using spectral graph theory and a laplacian matrix?

Comment: Can you give more details about what you're trying to do? What do you mean by "cut into $k$ parts"? Perhaps an example or two would help.

Comment: graph partition is a well known problem that involves calculating a separator composed of vertices or edges to be removed from the graph, so that connected subgraphs are left over. in this case i am working on the problem of political redistricting, where a graph of adjacent places is divided into k districts.

Comment: I suppose what is confusing me most is your second sentence. What do you mean by the same number of nodes "in a bunch"? Why is the number of partitions for this different than "all nodes in a row"?

Comment: sorry, that was some imprecise writing on my part. the two graphs i mean to compare are the complete graph and the path graph. a path graph of 4 nodes and 3 edges can be bipartitioned in 3 ways. a complete graph of 4 nodes and 6 edges can be bipartitioned in 6 ways. (i'm assuming there are not generally, as in this example, the same number of possible bipartitions as there are edges in the graph!)